# JavaScript array Filter (conditions not related to array elements )

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have below code

```
var numbersArray = [1, 3, 6, 8, 11];

var returnedArray = numbersArray.filter(function(number) {
  const condition = false // or true sometimes
  return number > 7 && condition ;
});

console.log(returnedArray); // Result is : []
```

The result will be an empty array `[];`

It is obvious that the result is empty because of the condition variable is false.
but as per the Mozilla MDN the definition of array filter is :

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

However, the ***condition*** variable here has nothing to do with array's elements.
I just want to know the explanation of the result to a junior dev like myself.

Comment: it (the description) looks fine to me, what is actually the part, you don't understand?

Comment: The test here is the condition based on which you return, even if its not related to the array directly. Whatever is evaluated in your `return` statement is the filter condition

Comment: See the definition ```The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.```. In your case, it not passes any of the tests. If it passes only one test then the filter will create a new array with the only value.

Comment: what is the value of `condition` when the number is `8` and `11` please print it

Comment: And it's not a fact is that the condition inside the callback function is related or not. If you return true or false it works.

Comment: you have to return `true` either for `8` or `11`

Comment: "test" here isn't a technical term, although it fits the general usage. The function passed to `filter` should take the array element (and, optionally, its index) and produce a Boolean expressing whether or not to include the element in the filtered array. That doesn't stop developers from using a "test" function which, as here, essentially ignores its input. But of course this isn't helpful in practice.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is, there is no need that `filter` method depends on the values inside the array

it offers a loop N time and gives you freedom of choice to do anything you want, it is upto you, that is the explanation you can provide to your junior

You can also refer another methodology called `predicate` which also offers such facility